# Запустить IIS контейнер Docker на Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: ubuntu, iis, docker

Суть проблемы: не устанавливается контейнер с IIS в Докере под Убунтой... Пытаюсь запулить контейнеры, получаю ошибки...

[image: Ошибки при пулле]

Вот страницы на Хабе Докера: https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/iis/ и https://hub.docker.com/r/nanoserver/iis/ ...

Контейнер microsoft/dotnet нормально скачался и запустился под Убунтой. Подскажите, что я не так делаю? Как запустить этот контейнер с IIS под Убунтой?

Answer (score 2):

**Контейнер [microsotf/iis](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/iis/) вы не можете запустить под Ubuntu.**

Контейнер [microsotf/iis](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/iis/) является *Windows Container-ом*, это описано в описании контейнера, поэтому вы его можете запустить только под операционной системой Windows, имея [бекенд Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/containers_welcome) в виде ядра операционной системы.

Контейнер [microsoft/dotnet](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/dotnet/) является же обычным LXC-подобным контейнером, поэтому вы его и смогли запустить под Ubuntu.

Comment: На странице контейнера https://hub.docker.com/r/nanoserver/iis/ написано, что он может запускаться под линуксом...  Может есть какие-то возможности обхода? Нужно просто сервер IIS стартовать для приложения на .NET ...

Comment: @Stanislav, я вам ответил про другой контейнер, про первый, он точно явялется windows-контейнером. Про второй -сейчас посмотрим.

Comment: @Stanislav,  второй контейнер тоже похоже на windows-контейнер, потому что он построен на основе nanoserver контейнера, а в нем явно прописано, что он windows-контейнер. У вас ASP.Net приложение? Если да, то контейнера microfost.dotnet достаточно, чтобы выполнить публикацию вашего приложения.

Comment: Я, честно говоря, мало понимаю в специфике iis и .Net... По идее, да, приложение .Net ... в папке первого проекта для iis содержатся основные: bin и etc... в bin лежат ModuleHosting (здесь разные файлы с расширениями: dll, pdb, exe, config, cmd) и Web (конфиги, библиотеки и снова странные pdb); а в etc, похоже, xml-конфиги проекта. В папке bin/Web второго проекта лежат: config, asax, стили, файлы js-скриптов и т.д. Видимо, для второго проекта iis точно необходим.